# Profile/Instrument a C++ Excel Addin in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, excel, profiling, instrumentation

I have an Excel addin written in C++. I can debug it by doing Debug>Attach to Process and selecting Excel.

Now I want to see where it is spending its time. It seems as if Performance Profiling Instrumentation is what I want, and from within that I can choose to attach to Excel. But when it is does it just tells me it spent time in unwalkable code. How do I see my routines in the report?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Excel addins are DLLs called by Excel. To debug in Visual Studio, one must attach to the Excel process rather than hitting F5. That works fine for me.  To do instrumentation/ performance profiling, a similar process is done, by telling VS to attach rather than run an exe. But the result of that says the program is spending its time in unwalkable code, whereas it should tell me how much time is spent in each of my functions. I am asking how I use VS to get the function timings.